# Best fitting circle to points in 3D

Tags: circles, 3d, svd, least-squares

I have a set of n ≥ 3 points in 3D that are measurements of a possible circle. The measured points are "noisy" so best-fitting algorithms are involved. I'm programming in C# and have put together some algorithms to do my procedure to find the best fitting circle to the points.

My procedure is the following:

1. Find the centroid **C (x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>, z<sub>0</sub>)** of the points.
2. Find the best fitting plane for the points using SVD. I now have a normalvector **N [a, b, c]** and a point **C**, fully describing the plane **P**
3. Orthogonal project all points to the plane
4. Subtract **C** from all points, such that **C** becomes the new origin **O** for the points. I now have a plane that crosses origin.
5. Translate the projected points into a 2D coordinate system that lies in the plane, using [this algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236540/2d-coordinates-of-projection-of-3d-vector-onto-2d-plane).
6. With the points now described in a 2D coordinate system, i can use [Levenberg-Marquardt](http://www.spaceroots.org/documents/circle/circle-fitting.pdf) to find the best fitting cirlce. This gives me a circle center **A (a, b)** and a radius **R**
7. The found circle center is described in the 2D coordinate system of the plane **P**

Now; my question:

> How do I translate the found circle center **A** to the original 3D coordinate system?

I've tried to do **A** + **C** but this produces the following, which places the circle center in the centroid of the points:

[image: Circle center is placed at the centroid of the points]

Comment: I agree with the process that you use. It is mainely the same as in paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/31477970/Regressions-et-trajectoires-3D , pages 28-32 , applied to ellipse, parabola and hyperbola in 3D. Circle is a particular case. The main difference is that the final fitting is not carried out with a Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm. It uses a direct method (no itteration, no guessed initial values). In case of circle, the direct fitting is explained pages 11-13 in the paper :  https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14819165/Regressions-coniques-quadriques-circulaire-spherique

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer my self.

Using notation from this question: [2D Coordinates of Projection of 3D Vector onto 2D Plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236540/2d-coordinates-of-projection-of-3d-vector-onto-2d-plane)

Find the matrix **M** that converts coordinates from the *X, Y, Z*-system to the coordinate system of the plane: *N, e'<sub>1</sub>, e'<sub>2</sub>*. This is a 3 x 3 matrix with e'<sub>1</sub> as row 1, e'<sub>2</sub> as row 2 and **N** as row 3. By taking the inverse (transpose) of this matrix you can convert coordinates the other way around.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)